# Deactivate all the greetings except the one that was activated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 4 greetings created. I want to activate one greeting at a time. When I activate one greeting, none of the other greetings should activate. How do I do this in Ruby on Rails? I have posted my code which activates all greetings:

```
def publish
  @seasonal_greeting_others = SeasonalGreeting.where(shop_id: @shop.id, published: true)
  @seasonal_greeting_others.each do |greeting|
    greeting.update_attributes(published: false)
  end

  @seasonal_greeting.update_attributes(published: true)

  redirect_to admin_seasonal_greetings_path
end

def unpublish
  @seasonal_greeting.update_attributes(published: false)
  redirect_to admin_seasonal_greetings_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback in your `SeasonalGreeting` model, `after_save`, for example:

```
after_save -> item { 
  where.not(id: item.id).where(shop_id: item.shop_id, published: true).update_all(published: false) 
}, if: :published
```

So each time you create or update a post with `published` `true` other posts with the same `shop_id` and `published` `true` are going to be updated with `false` value after the post is saved.

**Warning:** [`update_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) skips callbacks and validations as it is just a single `UPDATE` statement. If you need to run the callbacks/validations, you can use `update` for each instance found.

Comment: `update_all` might not be the best option here as it skips callbacks and validations

Comment: @MrYoshiji: true, but it really depends on the situation behind the OP's requirements, so I guess I should just update my post with a caveat you provided, if you don't mind, of course